# Splunk add field to each list of dict's element

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I've a Splunk json event like this:

```
{
  name: "my-name"
  tasks: [
    {
      id: 1,
      value: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      value: 2
    },
  ]
}
```

How to write a SPL command to return output with 2 records like:

```
{name: "my-name", id: 1, value: 1}
{name: "my-name", id: 2, value: 3}
```

Please help me, thank you guys !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually have ingested a valid JSON object, (as copied here your "json" event is not actually JSON, See the spec at [json.org](https://www.json.org/) ) but it's possible you copied the prettified version instead of the raw event.

And assuming you're on a new enough version of Splunk to have [JSON Functions](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/JSONFunctions) with eval...

```
<your search>
| fields name
| spath tasks{} output=task
| mvexpand task
| eval _raw=json_set(task,"name",name)
```

I simulated an event with this:

```
| makeresults | eval _raw=json_object("name", "my-name", "tasks", json_array(json_object("id", 1, "value", 1), json_object("id", 2, "value", 2))) | spath
```

Admittedly you could also use `| windbag | head 1` instead of `| makeresults` for simulation but that gets a bit into the obscure undocumented testing commands that happen to ship with the product.